# Set Limit On cursor Object before execute query in python

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-3.x, cursor

I have one query which I ran on mysql, mssql or oracle like

> select * from user

that query give me 0.5 million records/rows.
I want to get only 10 rows.
Below is python code :

```
 cursor.execute(query)
 columns = cursor.description
 rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

I tried using cursor.fetchmany(10) and that condition is giving me 10 row but it takes a lot of time. 
I want to set a limit before executing the query so that it will be not take much time and also got fast execution.
Please give me any solution in python.
Please help me...

Comment: can't you set condition on query itself, using rownum?

Comment: that query like a example any one random to pass query. but i need to set limit on my side. because i don't known how much data in this query. but i need only 10 rows.

Comment: what I am saying you can add/bind rownum to the query you are executing, otherwise you have to wait for query to return all the records then only you can filter it.

Comment: if query have nested or multiple joins with multiple table. If cursor object have that property then please tell me

Comment: can you please try setting this to 10 and then iterate over cursor intead of using fetchall, also break in first loop. http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.itersize

Comment: but still take lot of time in execution. I need to reduce execution time. Like java have that type of property using prepared statement. You can set statement.setFetchSize(500);

Answer (score 1):

When you only need 10 rows, use `select * from user LIMIT 10`.

Comment: I need to reduce execution time. Like java have that type of property using prepared statement. You can set statement.setFetchSize(500);

Comment: You can user SSCursor, but configuring fetch size doesn't reduce execution time on MySQL server side.
Adding LIMIT clause is much better than limit fetch size on client side.